# Why my app is getting this big?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 app which contains 50MB of musics, pictures and other data. the xap file gets about 60MB but when I install it on the phone, the size gets more than 150MB which is too big I think. more surprisingly, the project itself gets more than 2GB!

I looked at the project, the object folder and perflogs are the biggest.

Why should a panorama app with about 50MB of data and some kilo bytes of code get more than 150MB?

Comment: How big is the data when the XAP is extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAP file is at the end a zip compressed file, so if you app installed is about 150mb, you can extract your xap and take a look at what files weight more... Maybe there is more than 50Mb of media files.